# How to load a text file using application.yml in SpringBoot when Spring Cloud Config is used

Tags: spring-cloud-config

I am using Spring Cloud config to maintain the application properties in Gitlab
Is there a way to load a text file into a property?
I tried using the but the application only sees the string file://myfile.txt not its content.

```
my-app:
  file-content: file://myfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use the absolute path of the file instead of the relative path

```
my-app:
  file-content: file:D:\projct\my-project\resources/myfile.txt
```

I'm a Linux user and I am not sure about it is correct address or no :)